# ¿Cómo guardar el resultado de un procedimiento almacendado en un archivo de texto usando C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado ***(sp_help_revlogin)*** en la base de datos master de una instancia de base de datos en SQL Server. A continuación, el resultado de la ejecucíon:

```
EXEC sp_help_revlogin;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy intentando sin éxito, es guardar dicho resultado en un archivo de texto ejecutándolo desde un ETL que corre un script en C#. El siguiente código está bien resumido, pero básicamente esa es la lógica que pude armar.

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
#endregion

namespace ST_d59f37d9cd9f4882a6e0a79016b7da00
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]

    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a connection to the server
                string sqlConnectionString = "String conection";
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

                //Execute Stored Procedure
                string query = "EXEC sp_help_revlogin;";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                conn.Open();

                //ES AQUÍ MI PROBLEMA!!! (Cómo guardo el resultado del procedimiento)
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                //Create Path
                string FullPath = @"D:\Repository";
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(FullPath))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(FullPath);
                }
                
                //Set file Name
                string FileFullPath = FullPath +"\\" + "Logins.sql";
                ds.WriteXml(FileFullPath);

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                /* Code exeption */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Con la lógica anterior he podido crear las carpetas (Path) e inclusive crear el archivo, pero no he logrado escribir el resultado del stored en dicho archivo.

He encontrado muchos ejemplos en internet, pero básicamente son para casos en las que se consultan a tablas y por consiguiente los métodos son para recorrer y guardar columnas, pero en mi caso la salida es texto.

De modo que quisiera que por favor me ayuden a encontrar un método correcto para poder realizar lo expuesto líneas arriba.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te doy algunos pequeños matices al código expuesto.

Utiliza Command.Type como stored Procedure, y la query sólo el nombre del stored Procedure.

Ya que indicas en el comentario que el procedure, utiliza como salida la ventana de mensajes, para el ejemplo:

```
create procedure sp_info 
As
Begin
    Print 'Ejemplo salida 1';
    Print 'Ejemplo salida 2';
    Print 'Ejemplo salida 3';
    Print 'Ejemplo salida 4';
End;
```

Envuelve los objetos de uso de la base de datos en bloques using, para asegurarte el cierre y liberación de recursos.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("mensaje", typeof(string)));
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            try
            {
                // Create a connection to the server
                string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=HowTo;Integrated Security=true";

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(conn_InfoMessage);
                    conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
                    
                    //Execute Stored Procedure
                    string query = "sp_info";

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Connection.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    printFile();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                /* Code exeption */
            }


        }
        static void conn_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
        {
           ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(e.Message);
        }

        static void printFile()
        {
            try
            {
                //Create Path
                string FullPath = @"D:\Repository";
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(FullPath))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(FullPath);
                }

                //Set file Name
                string FileFullPath = FullPath + "\\" + "Logins.sql";
                if (ds != null)
                    ds.WriteXml(FileFullPath);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                /* Code Manejar excepciones de lectura y escritura IO Exception */
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Resultados]

Para procesar la salida de mensajes, utilizamos un evento a través de SqlConnection InfoMessage. A la misma se le puede asignar un manejador para controlar cada una de las salidas que se produzcan en el procedimiento.

[Evento InfoMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: gracias por responder, pero el código que te expuse también logra lo mismo que hiciste tú. Tal vez no fue preciso poner el método de escritura xml, pero lo puse porque no sé que otro método usar. Mi archivo no se escribe porque el stored que uso no tiene salida en grilla o tipo tabla como la que expones tú, el mio imprima un texto (print @text).

Comment: El hecho de que la query no se retorne como un select es un dato, bastante importante que has omitido de la pregunta. De la imagen no se puede extraer esa conclusión porque desde el ManagementStudio puedes poner como salida texto y queda exactamente igual que lo que has presentado. Te he cambiado el código para que veas como se capturan estos mensajes.

Comment: Gracias, con esa idea solo tuve que cambiar el método de escritura.